# sorting LEFT JOIN Select query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

i have two tables (products & products_price )
i want to sort product price rows to show as default price in left join query

for example : product id = 14 is two price item (num 31,25 in products_price table )

this single query result , show perfectly is that's i want :

```
SELECT  id ,p_id ,qty,price,CEILING(price-(price*discount_percent / 100)) AS off_price, CASE qty=0 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as not_zero_qty 
FROM products_price
WHERE status=1 AND p_id=14
ORDER BY not_zero_qty DESC,off_price ASC
```

[image : row id #31 is exactly for first show row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE3Rp.png) 
but when i put  this query in the LEFT JOIN query not working and row id #25 is frist row to show  :(

my LEFT JOIN query and result is :
[image : query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1aeX.png)

```
SELECT p.id,p.title,pp.price_id,pp.off_price
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  id as price_id ,p_id ,discount_percent,qty,price,default_price,CEILING(price-(price*discount_percent / 100)) AS off_price, CASE qty=0 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as not_zero_qty 
FROM products_price
WHERE status=1 
ORDER BY not_zero_qty DESC,off_price ASC ) pp 
ON p.id=pp.p_id 
WHERE  p.status=1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY pp.off_price DESC
```

Comment: Please don’t paste links to data in your question, add it as editable text directly in your question 1) It makes it difficult to understand your question if all the information is not visible in one place 2) If someone wants  to try a solution they need to be able to paste your data into their SQL editor; no-one is going to spend time manually re-keying your data

Comment: Can you format your queries? They are hard to read. You can use many of the online sql formatters.

Comment: First I agree with the previous comments. Second the "ORDER BY not_zero_qty DESC" is meaningless, you should take it to the outer select. And finally are you sure that you want to group products_prices according to their id's. It seems odd to me...

Comment: Your query is malformed.  The subquery in the `LEFT JOIN` has `SELECT` columns that are inconsistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.  Even if this happens to work on your database, the results are totally unstable and indeterminant.

Comment: @KemalKaplan  thank you  and sorry for my mistakes on writing this post,  i tried 3 days ago and i decision to use 'ORDER BY not_zero_qty DESC' for show frist and default price item , i have no idea , but that worked! , No , i guess its wrong to use 'GROUP BY price_id'

Comment: @GordonLinoff i removed GROUP BY in the SELECT query , but i have not found a solution to my problem , I got tired...

Comment: First of all: What DBMS are you using? You seem to want the lowest-price row per product. Yes? But you think you must outer join the prices, which indicates you think there are products without prices, and you still want to show these products. Is this so? You would usually use a lateral join for this. But not all DBMS (and usually not all versions of a DBMS) support lateral joins. You could use `ROW_NUMBER` for this, but again there are - mainly old - DBMS that don't support this. In these old DBMS an approach with  `NOT EXISTS` (a lower price) might be your best choice. What is your DBMS?

Comment: If it is MySQL you are using, please tell us which version. Many people still work with old MySQL versions lacking important features. Ranking queries, which is what you are loking for, have become much easier since MySQL version 8.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for your help . I'm using MySQL verion 8.0.8 on XAMPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the lowest price per product. I see that you are outer joining prices, so there are products without entries in the price table, and you still want to show those products. You are also considering quantities of 0 in your query such that you would prefer another row and only show the price for a zero amount in case there is no entry with a non-zero amount for the product in the table.

For this you have an `ORDER BY` clause that you want to use to rank your prices per product and only show the best ranked price (usually the least price above zero).

This is typically done with a lateral join, which MySQL doesn't support, yet. In MySQL you can use `ROW_NUMBER` instead to rank your rows:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, pp.price_id, pp.off_price
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT  
    id AS price_id,
    p_id,
    discount_percent,
    qty,
    price,
    default_price,
    CEILING(price - (price * discount_percent / 100)) AS off_price,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_id
                       ORDER BY (qty = 0),
                                CEILING(price - (price * discount_percent / 100))) AS rn
  FROM products_price
  WHERE status = 1 
) pp ON pp.p_id = p.id AND pp.rn = 1
WHERE p.status = 1
ORDER BY pp.off_price DESC;
```

Explanation: With `ROW_NUMBER` you number the price rows per product according to the desired order. Then you only keep a product's best ranked price row (`rn = 1`).

Comment: **Best Answer** , Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you put the query into the LEFT JOIN subquery, SORT BY makes no sense unless LIMIT is specified. Try moving ORDER BY to the outer level, kind of

```
SELECT p.id,p.title,pp.price_id,pp.off_price
     , pp.not_zero_qty 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (  
    SELECT  id as price_id ,p_id ,discount_percent,qty,price,default_price,CEILING(price-(price*discount_percent / 100)) AS off_price, CASE qty=0 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as not_zero_qty 
    FROM products_price
    WHERE status=1 
    GROUP BY price_id
    ) pp 
ON p.id=pp.p_id 
WHERE  p.status=1
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY not_zero_qty DESC, pp.off_price DESC
```

Comment: thanks @Serg , its not work , but result is one rows , even if i update qty of price items , 'ORDER BY not_zero_qty DESC' is Affects to whole of query but i want to use not_zero_qty , just for show Lowest item price with quantity that means if any off_price of price item is lower than other price and qty != 0 it should be displayed as the first row